# How can i change server directory in python from client?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, client-server

i'm trying to do client-server project. In this project i have to send linux command from client to server. Now i can send some commands like a ls, pwd etc. and they are running correctly and i can read output in client terminal but when i try to send "cd" command, i don't get any error but the directory in server doesn't change. If i use os.chdir(os.path.abspath(data)) command instead of subprocess.check_output , it can change directory but it is useless because i can send a other commands like a ls, pwd , mkdir etc. Thanks for your help

server side:

```
def threaded(c):
    while True:
        # data received from client
        data = c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            print('Bye')
            break
        try:
            data_o = subprocess.check_output(data, shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            c.send(b'failed\n')
            print(e.output)

        if(len(data_o) > 0):
            c.send(data_o)
        else:
            c.send(b'There is no terminal output.')

    # connection closed
    c.close()
```

client side:

```
while True: 
 # message sent to server 

        s.send(message.encode('ascii')) 
        # messaga received from server 
        data = s.recv(1024)
   # print the received message 

        print('Received from the server :',str(data.decode('ascii'))) 

        # ask the client whether he wants to continue 

        ans = input('\nDo you want to continue(y/n) :') 
        if ans == 'y':
            message = input("enter message")
            continue
        else: 
            break

    # close the connection 
    s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the command being sent is equal to `cd` and change the runtime behavior based on that.

```py
data_spl = data.split()

if data_spl[0] == 'cd':
    data_o = os.chdir(os.path.abspath(data_spl[1]))
else:
    data_o = subprocess.check_output(data, shell=True)
```